search is not working, SQL query doesn`t replace GridView data
This is the aspx code
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Client_tbl].[client_fullname],[Ticket_tbl].[client_phone],[Client_tbl].[client_email],[Client_tbl].[client_company],[Client_tbl].[client_id_num],[Client_tbl].[client_tax_num],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_category],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_shortdetails],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_details],[Ticket_tbl].[user_fullname],[Ticket_tbl].[user_branch],[ticket_date] FROM [Ticket_tbl] INNER JOIN [Client_tbl] ON [Ticket_tbl].[client_phone] = [Client_tbl].[client_phone] ORDER BY [Ticket_tbl].[ticket_id] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:GridView>`

This is the aspx.cs
protected void SearchButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            if (SearchTextBox1.Text != "" || SearchTextBox1.Text != null) {

                try
                {

                    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {

                        Conn.Open();

                    }

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User_tbl WHERE (user_name LIKE'%" + SearchTextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or user_fullname LIKE'%" + SearchTextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or user_branch LIKE'%" + SearchTextBox1.Text.Trim() + "%')", Conn);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                    da.Fill(ds);

                    GridView1.DataSourceID = "";

                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;

                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    Conn.Close();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");

                }

            }

            else {

                Response.Write("<script>alert('من فضلك ادخل كلمة للبحث');</script>");

            }

        }

The code is working for two pages where the data entries are few and there is no pagination.
Whats not working:
the page loads and the gridview shows the data, the search doesnt update the data of the gridview

You need to tell us what "not working" means. Also you have risk of SQL injection. And you're not using the "using" pattern.

Format the aspx code. Then you might have a chance that someone looks at that.

formatted the code, many thanks

The general approach is once you start to want "fancy" features such as data paging, and that of filtering?
That is the very same instant that you want to drop the use of SqlDataSource objects in the markup. In other words, they are a quick and easy solution when you don't need things such as filtering.
When you want to have code behind control of the GridView for special features like filtering and code control of the GridView data source?
It is at that point then I strong suggest you dump and remove the use of SqlDataSoruce objects in the markup, and use code behind to drive the GridView.
In fact, when using SqlDataSource in the markup means you actually can't control when the GirdView going to update, or even load - since it all auto "magic" for you. So, only use SqlDataSource objects in the markup for the simplest setup. Bonus points is they are ugly, messy, hard to work with, and as your question shows, they don't take well to you THEN wanting to control the GridView data with code behind.
So, with the above in mind, let's now setup the GridView to allow your filtering.
So, remove the SqlDataSource from the markup, and remove the SqlDataSource setting in the GridView markup.
So, say we have a GridView, and 2 search text boxes (one for hotel name, and one for city). Both are of course optional for filtering.
Hence, we now have this markup:
        <div style="float: left">
            <h3>Search For Hotel</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 35px">
            <h3>Search For City</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 35px">
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"
                CssClass="btn"
                OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />

        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <br />


        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkActive_CheckedChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

And now our code behind is this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strWhere = "";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
        if (txtHotel.Text != "") {
            strWhere = "(HotelName like @Hotel + '%')";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtHotel.Text;
        }

        if (txtCity.Text != "")
        {
            if (strWhere != "")
                strWhere += " AND ";

            strWhere += "(City like @City + '%')";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=txtCity.Text;
        }

        if (strWhere != "")
            strWhere = $" WHERE {strWhere}";

        cmdSQL.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA {strWhere} ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    

    }

And hence this:

And we can optionally filter by city, say like this:

In summary:
The example code is SQL injection safe. You never want to concatenate user input into your SQL strings since that is unsafe code and is vulnerable to SQL injection.
The example code does not use a SqlDataSource in the markup. This allows code behind control of the GridView loading. If you let ASP.NET automatic load the GridView for you with a SqlDataSource in the markup, then you can't control when the GridView reloads, or even when the refresh of the data will occur.
Also, if you want to add a data pager to the above, then you have to add the page indexing changed event, and that will look like this:
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="6"      
            OnPageIndexChanging="GVHotels_PageIndexChanging"
            >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkActive_CheckedChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>

And code behind for the pager code is this:
    protected void GVHotels_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GVHotels.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadGrid();
    }

And now we have the filter and data paging.

Last but not least?
It makes little sense to write connection and SQL command object code over and over. So, in a General class, I have this helper routine that will save you the pain of writing such code over and over.
public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }

Edit: Making it easy to write code and use SQL
Since I am suggesting to dump the use of SqlDataSources in the markup when you want to filter and use code behind to control the data source?
Well, while the SqlDataSource is messy, they are rather easy to create using the built in builders. Hence, we better adopt some "helper" routines, else all I done here is create a whole lot of extra work for you to manually write code for the SQL data source.
So, this means extra work for you, and to gain back some developer productivity and developer costs?
Then writing some "helper" routines to reduce the pain of writing such code now makes so much more sense. We don't live in a world in which we have unlimited time and unlimited software budgets.
Example:
Say we want to have a optional DropDownList filter (for city) in above to filter the GridView.
Say this markup:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server"
        DataTextField="City"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        width="200px">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="6"      
        OnPageIndexChanging="GVHotels_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
    </asp:GridView>

And now our code behind is this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCombo();
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City";
        string sCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEST4"].ConnectionString;

        DataTable dtCity = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sCon))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                dtCity.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            }
        }
        cboCity.DataSource = dtCity;    
        cboCity.DataBind();
        cboCity.Items.Insert(0, "Select City");
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        // Load GridView, check for combo box filter

        string sCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TEST4"].ConnectionString;

        string strWhere = "";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
        if (cboCity.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            strWhere = "WHERE (City = @City)";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA "
            + strWhere + " ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable dtHotels = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sCon))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open() ;
                dtHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());  
            }
        }
        GVHotels.DataSource = dtHotels;
        GVHotels.DataBind();    
    }



    protected void GVHotels_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GVHotels.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadGrid();
    }

    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

And the result is this:

Gee, above works great, but it also a lot of code and effort required.
Now, let's do the same with our helper routines.
So, in App_code, (or whatever folder you using for your general shared code in your application), then add this class:
public static class General
{


    public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        string sConn =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TEST4).ConnectionString;


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                rstData.TableName = strSQL;
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }



public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        string sConn =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TEST4).ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }

So, now with above helper code?
Then we have this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCombo();
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        cboCity.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City");
        cboCity.DataBind();
        cboCity.Items.Insert(0, "Select City");
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        // Load GridView, check for combo box filter
        string strWhere = "";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
        if (cboCity.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            strWhere = "WHERE (City = @City)";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA "
            + strWhere + " ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    
    }

I mean, wow! - look how easy the above code becomes to write, maintain, and read.
So, while I am asking you to dump the handy and easy to use SqlDataSource from the markup?
Then adopting some "helper" code now becomes far more critical, else the only end result of my suggesting here is you having to spend a whole lot more effort and time for my suggestion to dump those SqlDataSources in the markup.

thank you so much, your help is really appreciated :) would you please explain the last part where you use the helper routine for SQL

Sure, see my edit. I explain my reasoning behind adopting such "helper" code.
